# Control jQuery Easing using keyboard

Tags: jquery, keyboard, easing

I have jquery's easing plugin up and running on a very simple website, can be seen here: http://harrisonfjord.com/folio/

The code I have for anchor links (which call the jquery function to slide the window over to whichever div is pressed) is:

```
<a href="#" style="" onclick="Animate2id('#c1'); return false" rel="Greetings"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="" onclick="Animate2id('#c2'); return false" rel="About Us"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="Animate2id('#c3'); return false" rel="Plants Plus"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="Animate2id('#c4'); return false" rel="Kia Cadenza"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="Animate2id('#c5'); return false" rel="Panadol"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="Animate2id('#c6'); return false" rel="Asics"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="Animate2id('#c7'); return false" rel="Tooheys"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="Animate2id('#c8'); return false" rel="Channel 7 Olympic Coverage"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="Animate2id('#c9'); return false" rel="Hit us up!"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
<span style="font-size:25px" id="display"></span>
```

And the javascript code is as follows:

```
$(window).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
         //magical code goes here
    }
    return false;
});

function Animate2id(id,ease){ //the id to animate, the easing type
    var currentPage=id;
    var animSpeed=2000; //set animation speed
    var $container=$("#container"); //define the container to move
    if(ease){ //check if ease variable is set
        var easeType=ease;
    } else {
        var easeType="easeOutQuart"; //set default easing type
    }
    //do the animation
    $container.stop().animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, animSpeed, easeType);
}
```

I've tried setting up a variable for the Animate2id function that gets the current div that you're looking at, which could then be used to go to the next or previous div (but don't even know if I've done that correctly...).

Obviously still new to jquery/javascript so would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: OK ilooked at the live site, and the keyup for `t` works - but the animate `html, body` scrooll top? not sure that is right. Maybe like srolleft=0? yea?

Comment: Apologies, didn't realise the code was different on the site than what I posted here. I copied that code from elsewhere and was planning to edit around it. The goal here is to get the keypress (left/right) to figure out which div you're currently looking at and then move left/right of it (using jquery easing, preferably).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd amend your HTML, click handlers should be put in javascript. Use the `href` attribute to point to your related div:

```
<div id="link-container">
    <a href="#c1" style="" rel="Greetings"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#c2" rel="About Us"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#c3" rel="Plants Plus"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#c4" rel="Kia Cadenza"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#c5" rel="Panadol"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#c6" rel="Asics"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#c7" rel="Tooheys"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#c8" rel="Channel 7 Olympic Coverage"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#c9" rel="Hit us up!"><img src="img/btn1.jpg" /></a>
    <span style="font-size:25px" id="display"></span>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery, bind all the handlers:

```
$("#link-container A").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Animate2id($(this).attr("href"));   
});
```

Then in `Animate2id` add a class on the current `div`:

```
function Animate2id(id, ease){ //the id to animate, the easing type
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(id).addClass("current");

    // rest of this functions' code ...
}
```

With the class now on the selected `div` you can work out which direction you need to go in on left/right cursor press:

```
$(window).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which == 37) { // left cursor
         var $prevDiv = $(".current").prev("div");
         Animate2id($prevDiv.attr("id"))    
    }

    if (e.which == 39) { // right cursor
         var $nextDiv = $(".current").next("div");
         Animate2id($nextDiv.attr("id"))    
    }
});
```

Comment: My mistake, I've edited the answer. Change this line: `$(window).keyup(function(e) {`

Comment: Getting closer, although now the error when pressing a key is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null (regardless of which div I'm looking at)

Comment: I think that's because you already have a `#container` element in your code, and it's getting confused. I've updated the id of the container on the links to be `#link-container`, try that instead.

Comment: The menu container has an id of #menu (I already edited the references to it in your original post). I've updated the online version with your code if you'd like to see how it's misbehaving in practice: http://harrisonfjord.com/folio/

Comment: It is frowned upon to use A href tags as jquery triggers. Better use the `ID="Cx"` and bind to it using `$('#Cx').click` - then you wont need to disable default actions!

Comment: Let's get the left/right keyboard functions working first, then I'll sort out the triggers :)

Comment: The problem seems to be that the `$nextDiv.attr("id")' and '$prevDiv.attr("id")` aren't being passed along to the Animate2id function properly, because when the Animate2id function tries to go     `$container.stop().animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, animSpeed, easeType);` (the final line of its code) it's returning null, giving `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null`. Thoughts @RoryMcCrossan?